# Working fine on local but when deployed on vercel got this ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Tags: django-rest-framework, vercel, pythonanywhere

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_captcha(request):
    url = 'https://services.ecourts.gov.in/ecourtindia_v4_bilingual/cases/case_no.php?state=D&state_cd=1&dist_cd=23'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        html = response.text  
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        captcha_img = soup.find('img', id='captcha_image')
        print("captcha_img:", captcha_img)
        if captcha_img:
            image_url ='https://services.ecourts.gov.in'+captcha_img.get('src')
            print("Image URL:", image_url)
        else:
            print("Image URL not found.")

        return JsonResponse({"message": "hello", "image_url": image_url})

    else:
        print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Failed to fetch data from the URL"}, status=500)
```

It is working fine on my local server but when deployed it on Cloud Platform like vercel,pythonanywhere then it is giving **HTTPSConnectionPool(host='services.ecourts.gov.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ecourtindia_v4_bilingual/cases/case_no.php?state=D&state_cd=1&dist_cd=23 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))**

Comment: See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RequestingAllowlistAdditions/

Comment: it is not just above pythonanywhere.com but if I deploy on Any Hosting platform like vercel.com as well then also facing same issue.

Is this because I am trying to get the hit the government API through some public domain url and don't have allowed to do so ?